# Redshift Parse Dynamic Json String

Tags: sql, plsql, dynamic, amazon-redshift

I would like to be able to parse a dynamic json string in Redshift which is passed from a Stored procedure.  I was able to do this with postgres using code like below.

```
SELECT * FROM jsonb_each_text('{"name": "Bob", "age": "21", "section": "printing"}')
```

Which returned

```
key value
---    ------
age 21
name    Bob
section printing
```

Redshift has limited support for json objects and I was not able to get a function to work

Answer (score 0):

This is an UNPIVOTing of the object.

First you will need to convert your json to a super type if it isn't already.  Then you can follow the OBJECT UNPIVOTING section of the AWS doc here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for above unpivot may work

I have created a workaround below.  It splits the key value pair on the , and then by the :  I have some extra code to remove the {} and " and carriage return if there was any

```
select trim(SPLIT_PART(value,':',1))  as key,
       trim(SPLIT_PART(value,':',2)) as value
from
(
    SELECT 
        SPLIT_PART(array_values, ',',numval) AS value
    FROM 
        (
          select replace(replace(replace(replace(replace('{"name": "Alice","age": 25, "city": "Los Angeles"}','{',''),'}',''),chr(13),''),chr(10),''),'"','')::text as array_values
            ) array_data
    cross join
        (
         SELECT generate_series(1, 10) AS numval
        )
    where SPLIT_PART(array_values, ',',numval)  <> ''
) a
```